# Run-Time Error 380 "Invalid Property Value

Tags: printing, vb6

I tried to change printer size but when I run my code I got

> Run-Time Error 380 "Invalid Property Value

Here is my code:

```
If FormIndex > 0 Then
     Printer.PaperSize = FormIndex
     Printer.Orientation = vbPRORLandscape
     Me.PrintForm
     Printer.EndDoc
     MsgBox "Check Printer " & Printer.DeviceName, vbInformation, "Done!"
End If
```

Please any suggestion I have run same code on another appliction which is working fine

Comment: on which line you get error?

Comment: which printer you are using?

Comment: At this point `Printer.PaperSize = FormIndex` I got error. FormIndex value is 146

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the value. `FormIndex` were not recognized.

Try this:

```
Printer.PaperSize =vbPRPSLetter
```

You can refer to this **[LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.papersize.aspx)**

Comment: The values are the same, but this is the MSDN VB6 link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa245867%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
With Printer

  Printer.CurrentX = 1400
  Printer.CurrentY = 500
  Printer.Orientation = vbPRORLandscape
  Me.PrintForm
  Printer.EndDoc
  MsgBox "Check Printer " & Printer.DeviceName, vbInformation, "Done!"
end with
```

Comment: I am using EPSON TM-U220 and this does not support `Printer.CurrentX = 1400` and `Printer.CurrentY = 500` as well as `Printer.PaperSize = FormIndex` Do you have any idea how this property works on my current printer